# Integrals, Trig Substitutions with quartics: $\int{\frac{x}{{\left(x^2+2x+5\right)}^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to evaluate using trig substitution:
the indefinite integral

> $$\int { \frac { x }{ { \left( x^{ 2 }+2x+5 \right)  }^{ 2 } }  } dx$$

I can easily do problems with smaller terms like $\frac { 1 }{ x\sqrt { x-5 }  } $ but this problem is baffling me

Comment: Whenever you have polynomials, try completing the square

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**. By observing that
$$
(x^2+2x+5)^2=\left[(x+1)^2+4 \right]^2
$$ the change of variable
$$
x+1=2\tan u, \quad dx=2(\tan^2 u+1)du,
$$ gives
$$
\int\frac{x}{(x^2+2x+5)^2}\:dx=\frac1{8}\int \left(2\cos u \sin u-\cos^2 u \right)du
$$ which might be easier to evaluate.

Comment: isnt dx the derivative of 2tanx-1 which is 2sec^2x, not 2(tan^2x+1)

Comment: @BobDoe Please, observe that $$2\sec^2 u=2\frac1{\cos^2u}=2\frac{\sin^2u+\cos^2u}{\cos^2u}=2(\tan^2 u+1).$$

Comment: While solving i reduced the integral to cos^2x, aside from integrating it is there a way to simplify it further before integration